# Php update view count

Tags: php, sql

I am kind of new to PHP and have not had a chance to get the update function to work yet.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
include('config.php');

$user_info = fetch_user_info($_GET['AccountNumber']);

$update= 'UPDATE `content` SET `ViewCount ` = `ViewCount ` + 1 WHERE `AccountNumber` = : AccountNumber LIMIT 1';


$statement = $db->prepare($update);
$statement->bindParam(':AccountNumber', $_POST['AccountNumber'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

So basically it connects to my database, finds the user based on the account number inside of the url and then it's supposed to pull how many views that account already has and add one but it's

Comment: Update your question with a full sentence?  We don't really have enough information to answer.  Currently you're displaying the setting of a string that happens to hold what looks like part of a query that requires a bind variable.  Do you actually run the query and bind the variable (AccountNumber)?  You also have some odd random spaces inside of your names, that could be problematic.

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize any data from your users.

Comment: You don't need to sanitize incoming data via PDO with properly escaped data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include('config.php');

$user_info = fetch_user_info($_GET['AccountNumber']);

$update= 'UPDATE `content` SET `ViewCount ` = `ViewCount ` + 1 WHERE `AccountNumber` = :     AccountNumber LIMIT 1';


$statement = $db->prepare($update);
$statement->bindParam(':AccountNumber', $user_info, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

or

```
$statement->bindParam(':AccountNumber',$_GET['AccountNumber'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Instead of the last line in the above example.

Since I have no idea what the $user_info is- a number, string, array etc. Those are a couple possibilities.

You had a $_POST['AccountNumber'] in the bindParam(... line of your code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```
session_start(); 
if(!empty($_SESSION['view'])){
    $update= 'UPDATE `TABLENAME` SET `ViewCount ` = `ViewCount ` + 1 WHERE      
       `AccountNumber` = : AccountNumber LIMIT 1';
    $_SESSION['view'] = "updated";
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that is supposed to be solving?

Comment: Session? Did you even attempt to read the question?

Comment: hmmm still can't get any of this to work